# Деление с округлением в большую сторону

Tags: c#, математика, деление

**`Math.Round`** округляет по правилу, как заставить его округлять в **большую** сторону, или какую другую функцию использовать?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.95).aspx) - к большему целому

[Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.95)) - к меньшему целому